# How we can access search api of flipkart in my asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

Hiii, I am using product feed JSON API of flipkart, It is working good but if I am using  API Search Query based on Keywords no result found and getting no error. please help me if it is possible. For product search api I am using this code-

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();       
wc.Headers.Add("Fk-Affiliate-Id", "My Fk-Affiliate-Id"); 
wc.Headers.Add("Fk-Affiliate-Token", "My Fk-Affiliate-Token");                
var temp = "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/search/json?query+txtWeb.Text;           
var getjson= wc.DownloadString(temp);    
Response.Write(getjson);
```

Comment: I tried in php. And same thing.. No results, No error. Did the issue solved to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
 string Producturl="url string"; // Here filpkart API
 var wc = new WebClient(); // Create Webclient Object   
 wc.Headers.Add("Fk-Affiliate-Id", "value");  // In value Replace WIth your Affilicate Id 
 wc.Headers.Add("Fk-Affiliate-Token","value");  // In value Replace WIth your Affilicate-Token-Id 
 string productFeedXml =    wc.DownloadString(Producturl);
```

========================================================================

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Also, please format your code properly, using Markdown.